MILP algorithm using pulp
I am trying to create a AES-like crypto system. I would like to perform linear and differential cryptanalysis in Python. I can plot the DDT, LAT table, but I am not able to create the MILP (Mixed Integer Linear Programming) algorithm using the pulp library.
How can I find the minimum number of active S-boxes in a crypto- system with respect to DDT and LAT table? Where I can find a MILP algorithm for AES that doesn't require external cryptographic libraries?
Please note that I am beginner when it comes to cryptanalysis.
